# Azure Blockchain Workbench app not showing up among Enterprise Applications

Tags: azure, blockchain, azure-blockchain-workbench

I have just deployed an Azure Blockchain Workbench. It shows up in AD among "App registrations", but it doesn't show up among "Enterprise applications." Because of this, I can't assign admin role to any users and I'm stuck, can't use the workbench.

What should I do to make it appear among the "Enterprise applications"?

Answer (score 1):

Which Active Directory tenant are you working under? If it is the Microsoft tenant, then you wouldn't be having Administrative rights. Thus you will not be able to assign admin roles to anyone.
You will need to create a new AD tenant where you are the administrator.
Hope this helps.

This walkthrough should help - 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/blockchain/tree/master/blockchain-workbench/scripts/aad-setup

Answer (score 1):

When you open the App Registration what do you see in the "Managed application in local directory" section? If there's a link, can you click on it? It should take you to the enterprise application.

[image]